Random pulse generator
I am trying to emulate the arrival of random interrupts to a microcontroller pin and am wondering what is the easiest way of achieving that.
Specifically, I want to connect something to a microcontroller pin so that it pulsates that pin at random intervals.
Is there something off the shelve that I can use or would I need to build some custom circuit.

Use a second microcontroller.

How frequently do you require these pulses, on average? Every few seconds? every few milliseconds?

If you define the shortest and longest interval between IRQ's there is an algorithm for maximal length sequence using XOR feedback in a shift register together called a PRSG that may be defined as a 1 or 0  or a pulse.;

Do you really want something connected to the pin, is it enough if the MCU triggers interrupts with e.g. timer interrupt, where you set the period to next interrupt via a pseudorandom value?

It really matters the timing you need please specify what signal you want to generate

it all depends on your purpose.  Debug? self-test? performance tests?

It seems if you are too slow to respond to questions, the Mods will close your question until you provide answers or edits.

Thanks all for your input. To add a bit of context, I am trying to evaluate the performance of a number aperiodic servers (like poller, defferable, sporadic) and ideally I would like the aperiodic events to be truly random. As @Justme mentions one way is to set up a timer with a value generated pseudorandomly by the MCU (an STM32F429 in my case) but that would burn a few cycles both in the code setting registers and timers up and in the generation of the value itself, which I'd like to avoid. Hence, I am looking to have something entirely external generating those events.

ChatGPT seems to be suggesting a solution which involves a Zener diode in reverse bias which will presumably generate some noise which is then amplified and fed into a comparator which outputs a HIGH when the amplified voltage is over a certain threshold which is then fed into a monostable multivibrator which is finally fed into a flip-flop to generate the actual pulses that will be fed into the pin. You wouldn't be aware of any off the shelve component that does all that, would you? :)

@Sidisyom  Sort of yes I do. The F429 contains a true random number generator. However it may be too slow for your purpose, but you can seed a software PNRG/LFSR or use the CRC calculator unit as LFSR. Or buy one STM32 eval board and let it generate the random pulses for these other MCUs. Or connect the zener to that MCU and read it as analog value. There is really no point asking ChatGPT for help or use reverse biased zeners, MCUs are better and lets you be in charge what pulse periods you need.

@Justme, a second MCU that feeds the main one sounds like the most straightforward option, thanks!


It seems if you are too slow to respond to questions, the Mods will close your question until you provide answers or edits. Not sure if I need to configure something here but I didn't get any notification emails about these responses..


If you have no clue, it is a bad idea to ask chat bots for help. They do not have a clue, too. Their answers are far too often wrong.

This can be implemented as a self-test using an algorithm of a Pseudo-Random Sequence Generators (PRSG) or Linear Feedback Shift Registers (LFSR) to record the latency, tolerance, accuracy and handling durations of various IRQ's with various loads.

The sequence length can be maximal: \$2^{n−1}\$  where n is the number of bits in the register.
The initial condition can be anything except all 1's for non-inverting feedback or visa-versa.
The shortest interval is determined by the clock 1/0 state or edge if you prefer. The longest interval would be N clk's
The random distribution is based on cycles / Hz of BW.
or use the random command to program an I/O timer which could be salted to be non-repeatable.

You may want to combine repetitive (real-time) IRQ's with Pseudo-Random and decremented intervals to find breaking points.
Steps:

Define the purposes
Design the algorithm
Implement in C
Integrate algorithm to send IRQ's or GPIO
Define the test plan based on design specs, use a logic analyzer to measure, log missed events
Hire someone to do this for you, or try GPT4 et al the others and say "are you sure?"


Hi @D.A.S, thanks for your input, I am actually looking for an external circuit solution, please see my comments above.

f max? Yes There are tools to do this but what are your specs Max/Min ratio?  It can be done on a breadboard in 1/2 h if you just want quick n dirty with a pot and a logic analyzer to measure.
